# Anchor link without creating history entry

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, anchor

I can link to somewhere on a webpage with an anchor link like this:

```
<a href="#MyAnchor">Go to MyAnchorText</a>

<p id="MyAnchor" class="boldtitle">MyAnchorText</p>
```

But this has a disadvantage: If you click e.g. five times on anchor links, you also have to click the browser back button six times to return to the webpage you visited before you visited the current web page.

Is there a way to link to somewhere on a page without creating a history entry each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I now have the following code that is working perfectly:

```
<script>
function scrollToAnchor(selectedAnchor) {
    document.querySelector(selectedAnchor).scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth'
    });
}
</script>

<a onclick="scrollToAnchor('#MyAnchor');">Go to MyAnchorText</a>

<p id="MyAnchor" class="boldtitle">MyAnchorText</p>
```